# How use zigbee4java and mac os x?

Tags: macos

I want use [zigbee4java](https://github.com/tlaukkan/zigbee4java) project, but how use com ports in mac os x?

I need something like this:

`ZigBeeConsole.main(new String[]{
        "COM5", "11", "4954", "true"
});`

this works on windows computers.